# Можно ли обратиться к безымянному экземпляру класса (например по id объекта) в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Не совсем понимаю, как обратиться к безымянному экземпляру класса (например, при создании этого экземпляра в цикле). Как потом взаимодействовать с такими экземплярами (изменять атрибуты, применять к ним методы класса)?

К примеру:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, day, month, year, title):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.title = title

for instance in range(6):
    x = 1
    Task(day=x, month=3, year=2020, title='bla-bla')
    x += 1
```

Так, тут должны создаться 5 экземпляров класса `Task` с разными атрибутами `day`, но я не знаю как к ним обратиться, и как с ними взаимодействовать. Пожалуйста, подскажите, имеется ли какое-то простое решение

Comment: В цикле добавляйте экземпляры класса в список.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите объекты `Task` в список или в словарь (если нужен доступ к задаче по ключу).

Пример для списка:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, day, month, year, title):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.title = title

task_list = []

for x in range(6):
    task = Task(day=x+1, month=3, year=2020, title='bla-bla')
    task_list.append(task)

print(len(task_list), task_list)

# После можно через цикл обратиться к задачам и что-то сделать
for task in task_list:
    task.run()
```

Comment: спасибо, применительно к формулировке моего вопроса, решение идеальное. Однако у меня проблема немного иного рода, нежели я сам ее обозначил, чтобы упростить пример и не крепить слишком много кода. Я описал все в комментарии к ответу выше, отвечая пользователю insolor. Прошу прощения, что ввел в заблуждение, надо было четче описывать проблему.

Comment: @Kaderma, если собираетесь с базой работать, то обеспечьте поле `Id` вашим задачам, это минимум. Самое простое -- использовать `sqlite3`, создадите там таблицу `Task` ее поля будут совпадать с теми что у класса, после сможете добавлять в базу новые `Task` или считывать из нее (нужно будет сделать сериализацию, чтобы поля таблицы базы соответствовали полям класса). Либо, чтобы упростить выше написанное, используйте библиотеки для базы, поддерживающие ORM, например peewee или sqlalchemy, тогда сможете дописать `Task` и тот сможет сохранять себя в базу.

Comment: @Kaderma, т.е. `Task` не просто в оперативной памяти сохранять, а в базе данных, тогда при запуске будут считаны из базы `Task`, и, например, в ходе работы программы проверяться на указанную дату. А так, если у вас будут вопросы по созданию Task в базе данных, то создайте новый вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, мне стало понятно направление, в котором теперь нужно копать

Answer (score 5):

Чтоб обратиться к объекту - на него нужна ссылка.

Если ссылки нет - этот объект вскоре удалится.

Ссылку можно положить в переменную или в список или передать другой функции параметром.

Comment: тогда не понимаю, как в цикле разным экземплярам присвоить разные переменные. Другими словами: как сделать для каждого экземпляра уникальную переменную со своим именем, которая хранила бы ссылку на определенный экземпляр созданного в цикле класса

Comment: @Kaderma, зачем заданиям уникальные имена переменных? Положите 6 заданий в список, обращайтесь к отдельным заданиям по индексу.

Comment: @insolor, пример с циклом я привел для упрощения, дабы не крепить огромную простыню кода, мало имеющего отношения к задаче. На самом деле у меня есть простенький графический интерфейс на ткинтер, где одни аргументы класса `Task` будут приниматься от параметров виджета (day, month, year), а другие вводится пользователем (title). Потом мне нужно будет отправлять полученные значения атрибутов в какую-нибудь БД и объявлять функцию для этого внутри самого класса `Task`. Поэтому мне и нужно обращаться к конкретному экземпляру, дабы иметь возможноть тут же применить к нему метод его класса.

Comment: @insolor, прошу прощения за свой поток сознания, надеюсь, что это возможно разобрать(поэтому я и решил на примере цикла вопрос сформулировать)

Comment: Можно ещё в очередь положить...

Comment: @Kaderma, еще раз: добавлять объекты в список. Обращаться к каждому отдельному экземпляру по индексу.